# Regex to capture HTTP cookies

Tags: regex, http

I'm writing a Regex to capture HTTP cookies:

```
([^=]+)=([^\;]+);\s?
```

Here's a sketch:

https://regex101.com/r/cq9ipS/1/

As you can see, it only finds the first `key=value ;`. So I tried to add a `+` at the end to capture everything inside parenthesis more than one time:

```
(([^=]+)=([^\;]+);\s?)+
```

But then it only captures the last expression, not all of them.

What is happening?

Comment: Regex is a wrong tool here, there should be methods to manipulate the cookies. What language are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the g modifier to your regex, otherwise it stops after the first match i.e.

```
/([^=]+)=([^\;]+);\s?/g
```

From regex101:

g Tells the engine not to stop after the first match has been found, but rather to continue until no more matches can be found.

Comment: hmmm, but if I put Set-Cookie: in front of it I cannot anymore search for multiple occurrences. Isn't there a way to make something like  `Set-Cookie:(([^=]+)=([^\;]+);\s?)+` ?

Comment: Why do you need to add Set-Cookie: ?

Comment: To prevent the regex from finding things on other HTTP variables

Comment: The simplest solution would be to match against /^Set-Cookie: / and then against this regex.